# JavaScript: Anonymous vs Helper function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I'm trying to understand this functional style code from the book Eloquent Javascript:

http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html#exercise1

When the count() function passes an anonymous function to reduce() the code works. But if I break the function out into a helper function then I get a reference error.

Can anyone explain why count() works but countHelper() does not?

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0]

function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

function reduce(combine, base, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}

function equals(x) {
  return function(element) { return x === element;};
}

function count(test, array) {  
  return reduce(function(base, element) {
    return base + (test(element)?1:0);
  }, 0, array);
}

function countHelper(test, array) {
  function helper(base, element) {
    return base + (test(element)?1:0);
  }
  return reduce(helper(base, element), 0, array);
}

function countZeroes(array) {
  return count(equals(0), array);
}

print(countZeroes(numbers)) // 2

function countZeroesHelper(array) {
  return countHelper(equals(0), array);
}

print(countZeroesHelper(numbers)) // ReferenceError: base is not defined
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `countHelper()`, you are actually calling the helper function immediately when you pass arguments to `reduce()` and passing its return value to reduce (which isn't what you want), rather than passing a reference to the function so `reduce()` can call the function when it wants to.  You have this:

```
function countHelper(test, array) {
  function helper(base, element) {
    return base + (test(element)?1:0);
  }
  return reduce(helper(base, element), 0, array);
}
```

It should be this:

```
function countHelper(test, array) {
  function helper(base, element) {
    return base + (test(element)?1:0);
  }
  return reduce(helper, 0, array);
}
```

Note the difference in arguments to the `reduce()` function.

When you want to pass a function as an argument, you don't include the parens after it because that just causes it to be executed right away and passes the return value from executing it rather than just passing a reference to the function itself.

This is a common mistake in an untyped language like Javascript that lets you pass anything in any argument.  Even seasoned programmers occasionally make this mistake (myself included).  The important distinction to understand is the difference between executing the function vs. passing a reference to the function.